# Adding 64bit support to cordova ios app using xcbuild / xcrun and xcconfig

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am working on a cordova app and I managed to create the ipa from command line with a script.

```
echo "" > $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXX" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = \$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 7.0" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig

cordova build ios --device

xcrun \
  -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication \
  -v "$PRODUCT_DIR/$TARGET.app" \
  -o "$OUTDIR/$TARGET.ipa" \
  --embed "$PROVISONING_PROFILE" \
  --sign "$IDENTITY"
```

This works just fine, but I get this warning when I upload to Apple TestFlight.

[image]

Do you guys have any hint on this? Maybe I can add a line in the `.xcconfig` which seems pretty handy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured what was wrong! The `--release` flag was missing. Now I can build without opening XCode!

```
echo "\n > patching cordova xconfig for distribution\n"
echo "" > $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = $IDENTITY" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = \$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig
echo "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 7.0" >> $PROJECT_DIR/cordova/build.xcconfig

echo "\n > cleanup $OUTDIR/$TARGET.ipa\n"
rm -vf $OUTDIR/$TARGET.ipa

echo "\n > build project\n"
cordova build ios --release --device

echo "\n > creating ipa at $OUTDIR/$TARGET.ipa\n"
cd $BASE_DIR
xcrun \
  -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication \
  -v "$PRODUCT_DIR/$TARGET.app" \
  -o "$OUTDIR/$TARGET.ipa" \
  --embed "$PROVISONING_PROFILE" \
  --sign "$IDENTITY"
```

Comment: I believe that was my issue as well! Thanks for posting!

Comment: Actually, iTunes is still reporting that 64 bit is not supported, even though I no longer see that error in Application Loader.

Comment: iTunes or iTunes connect? screenshot?

Comment: Email from iTunes Connect:"Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code."

Comment: Looks like my scripts were calling "cordova build ios --device" in more than one place... I've corrected it in both places, and will post more info if it works now.

Comment: Yep, this seems to have worked when I made sure that "--release" was present everywhere I did a build. THANKS!

Comment: This post saved my day. Thanx a lot @kilianc.